About Property of double integrals
If I have $\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} {f(x, t)} \, g(x, t) \, (-dx) \, (-dt) $ then is this can be rewritten as:
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {f(x, t)} \, g(x, t) \,dx \, dt $ ?
I am confused because of those two negative signs. As $-\times-=+$ and hence there will be no negative sign left to use the property $\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} {f(x)} (-dx)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {f(x)} \, dx$
Please help....

@zkutch sir, I think no, the last equality is satisfied when the limits are finite? Sir, But what about the first? When they are equal?

@zkutch sir, first is correct? Means those two double integrals are equal? How? Can you please explain. Moreover, why the last is incorrect?

@zkutch Yes, I agree. But, that doesn't show how last equality is incorrect. Moreover, from this, how it follows that those two double integrals are equal

Sir, you said in your previous comment that, Infinite bounds comes from limit, so rules for sign keeps for improper integrals too. So how $\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} {f(x)} (-dx)≠\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {f(x)} , dx$

Swapping the limits of integration results in a sign change:
$\displaystyle \int_a^b g(u)\,du = -\int_b^a g(u)\,du$
So in your case, you have $4$ sign changes (two swaps of limits and two negative differentials). Since $4$ is even, the net result is to not have any sign change:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} f(x, t) \, g(x, t) \, (-dx) \, (-dt)
&= \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty} f(x, t) \, g(x, t) \, dx \, dt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x, t) \, g(x, t) \, dx \, dt. 
\end{aligned}
$$

Sir, thanks for the answer. Can you provide any reference for this? (I don't know who downvoted it...)

Where are you studying calculus? This is a standard result in any textbook or introductory course. The proof from Riemann sums is straightforward as well.

Alternatively, one can show that for any integrable function $g$ and any three real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$,
$$
\int_a^b g(u),du + \int_b^c g(u),du = \int_a^c g(u),du.
$$
Taking this together with the fact that
$$
\int_a^a g(u),du = 0,
$$
the identity about swapping limits follows by setting $c = a$:
$$
\int_a^b g(u),du + \int_b^a g(u),du = \int_a^a g(u),du = 0.
$$

Sir, but those above properties are for definite integral? Are they hold in my case too? Moreover, please give any reference specifically for such properties of double integrals/multiple integrals.
